# Unable to get properties(e.g.Name,Path) from User [ADSI ] in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: powershell-3.0, adsi

I am new to Powershell. I am trying to find out all local/domain users under
all the local groups from different Windows machines.

I found below script for this purpose. When I run this script in Windows 7 Ultimate, it does not get any member properties (e.g. Name, Path) for local groups found in this machine.

```
 Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
[ADSI]$S = "WinNT://$($env:computername)"
$S.children.where({$_.class -eq 'group'}) |

Select @{Name="Members";Expression={
[ADSI]$group = "$($_.Parent)/$($_.Name),group"
$members = $Group.psbase.Invoke("Members")
($members | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ";"}
} 
} | Select Members
```

It seems that below line of code does not work(does not fetch properties (e.g. name ) of the user)

```
ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ";"}
```

Same script works well in Windows 10  and Windows 2012.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4b341b82-83c2-4def-a627-3db8c01009fe/unable-to-get-propertiesegnamepath-from-user-adsi-in-windows-7-ultimate?forum=winserverpowershell).Copying answer from the link.

There are many issues with your script that will cause bad behavior on different systems and versions.

Here is a general method that works anywhere.  DO NOT use Invoke-Command.  ADSI works remotely just fine.

```
$computer = $env:computername
$groups = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$computername").Children | Where{$_.class -eq 'group'}
foreach($group in $groups){
    $group.Invoke("Members") |
        ForEach-Object {
            $type = $_.GetType()
            $name = $type.InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            [pscustomobject]@{Group=$group.Name[0];Account=$name}
        }
}
```